# Using rdiff/bsdiff to go from an original version of a file (v0.1), to a new version (v0.2) in the best time/storage/load way

Tags: algorithm, go, delta, rdiff, bsdiff

Take the scenario
I want to create backups along the way while working on a file (photoshop/word/powerpoint etc (e.g binary data)), so each time I create a v0.x I create a backup of it too.
However I want to use rdiff to do this, so that I only have to store the pieces that diff between the original version and the current version.

I am [using the code found here](https://github.com/jbreiding/rsync-go) and my code (that runs) is as follows

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"

    "github.com/jbreiding/rsync-go"
)

var originalFile string
var newFile string
var patchFile string
var signatureFile string
var appliedFile string

func openFile(path string) ([]byte, error) {
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(path)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("File reading error", err)
    }
    return data, err
}

func writeFile(path string, data []byte) error {
    err := ioutil.WriteFile(path, data, 0644)
    return err
}

func main() {
    originalFile = "./profile-shot.jpg"
    newFile = "./profile-shot-to.jpg"
    patchFile = "./profile-shot.patch"
    signatureFile = "./profile-shot.sig"
    appliedFile = "./profile-shot-applied.jpg"

    //create a signature based on the original file
    originalFileReader, _ := os.Open(originalFile)
    defer originalFileReader.Close()

    rs := &rsync.RSync{}

    //take a signature of the new
    //apply it to the original
    //get a delta
    //apply the delta to the original
    //get the new??

    // 1. prepare a signature
    sig := make([]rsync.BlockHash, 0, 10)
    writeSignature := func(bl rsync.BlockHash) error {
        sig = append(sig, bl)
        return nil
    }

    //2. take the new file
    newFileReader, _ := os.Open(newFile)

    //3. create the signature
    rs.CreateSignature(originalFileReader, writeSignature)
    sigBytes, err := json.Marshal(sig)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error ", err)
    } else {
        writeFile(signatureFile, sigBytes)
    }

    opsOut := make(chan rsync.Operation)

    dataWriter := bufio.NewWriter(&dataBuffer)
    //4. specify a write operation for the delta
    writeOperation := func(op rsync.Operation) error {
        opsOut <- op
        data, err := json.Marshal(op.Data)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("error ", err)
        }
        if _, err := dataWriter.Write(data); err != nil {
            fmt.Println("error writing data ", err)
        }
        return nil
    }
    var dataBuffer bytes.Buffer
    go func() {
        defer close(opsOut)
        //5. in a routine, create a delta from the new image and the signature of the original
        err := rs.CreateDelta(newFileReader, sig, writeOperation)
        fmt.Println("err creating delta ", err)
        writeFile(patchFile, dataBuffer.Bytes())
        fmt.Println("length of signature ", len(sig))
        //now we have written the patch to file, we can open the applied file and write the data from the patch to it, by passing the struct(s) to a new opsOut channel, and calling apply delta using that channel
    }()

    // saving the applied delta resulting file
    newFileWriter, err := os.OpenFile(appliedFile, os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE, 0600)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error source writer ", err)
    }
    originalFileReader.Seek(0, os.SEEK_SET)
    //6. apply the delta
    rs.ApplyDelta(newFileWriter, originalFileReader, opsOut)
}
```

Above does basically what I think is expected of rdiff.

- Read in the original file (v0.1)
- Create a signature from this file (v0.1 sig)
- Create a delta, which is based on the **new** file (v0.x) and the signature
- Apply the delta to v0.1 and you will get v0.x

The issue then, is that in reality, I am likely to have a backup of v0.1 and all the signatures of each following version, and **not** have backups of each full version (which is pointless).

However the above requires the new version to create the delta, not the original version. So in effect I can't go backwards, because I cant create the deltas when I need them without the newer version, and its the new version that I am trying to get using rsync.

I realise that the solution is to store the delta, however so far (using images) the delta is as big as the files themselves (I'm using images between 20MB and 100MB for testing). It therefore also doesn't seem worth it using this method.

Note. I have also been using [bsdiff in Go](https://github.com/icedream/go-bsdiff) and this does do the trick (deltas about 0.5 time the size of the actual files) however its very slow due to a sorting algorithm that generates an index. This index is required to create the diff. It's about 10x the size of the original files so storing that is also not an option.

Any ideas as to the best approach here, would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

minimize delata ideas:

```
diffData:=diff(decompress(oldImage),decompress(newImage))
```

(You need a fast binary diff algorithm)

```
newImage:=recompress(patch(decompress(oldImage),diffData))
```

(the recompress algorithm requires: result new newImage must be same as it before diff )

this way is also the idea of processing zip file...

diff algorithm: bsdiff is slow & requires large memroy, xdelta3 (or HDiffPatch -s) may be more appropriate here, less memroy and fast;

recompress: for re-compress speed and recovery, it may be necessary to save some meta information when decompress;